# Refresh, find and alert using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code that is supposed to be refreshing a given web page after a specific amount of time and tries to find a certain word after each refresh. And when that word is found, a certain alarming sound is supposed to go off.
here's the code:

```js
javascript:
  var myRegExp = prompt("the word");
timeout = prompt("the time in seconds");
current = location.href;
setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
var audio = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2197&type=mp3');

function reload() {
  var found = searchText();
  if (!found) {
    setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
    fr4me = '<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame id="frame01" src=\'' + current + '\'/>';
    fr4me += '</frameset>';
    with(document) {
      write(fr4me);
      void(close())
    };
  }
}

function searchText() {
  var f = document.getElementById("frame01");
  if (f != null && f.contentDocument != null) {
    var t = f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    var matchPos = t.search(myRegExp);
    if (matchPos != -1) {
      audio.play();

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

My question/request is, how to make the alarming sound plays on endless loop when triggered? **Answered**

And also, how to make the search for the word case insensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```js
myAudio = new Audio('yoursound.mp3'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: thanks man! is there anyways that you would know how to make the search for the word case insensitive?

Comment: @AhmedAlarbi just transform everything to lower case (or upper case) while searching

Comment: I don't think you got my question, i just want to make the code look for the word "example" weather it was like this "EXAMPLE", like this "example" or even like this "ExAmPlE"