# case insensitive search in javascript

Tags: javascript, case-insensitive

I have this javascript code that is supposed to be refreshing a given web page after a specific amount of time and tries to find a certain word after each refresh. And when that word is found, a certain alarming sound is supposed to go off. here's the code:

```js
javascript:
  var myRegExp = prompt("the word");
timeout = prompt("the time in seconds");
current = location.href;
setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
var audio = new Audio('http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=2197&type=mp3');

function reload() {
  var found = searchText();
  if (!found) {
    setTimeout('reload()', 1000 * timeout);
    fr4me = '<frameset cols=\'*\'>\n<frame id="frame01" src=\'' + current + '\'/>';
    fr4me += '</frameset>';
    with(document) {
      write(fr4me);
      void(close())
    };
  }
}

function searchText() {
  var f = document.getElementById("frame01");
  if (f != null && f.contentDocument != null) {
    var t = f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    var matchPos = t.search(myRegExp);
    if (matchPos != -1) {
      audio.play();

      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

My question/request is, how to make the search for the word case insensitive?

Comment: Just lowercase the search text. And then perform the match. `f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh, find and alert using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54855788/refresh-find-and-alert-using-javascript)

Comment: Please, don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: @jo_va it's the same code, but the question is different

Comment: It is not, from the other question: and also, how to make the search for the word case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the `ignoreCase` option**
From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase)

> The ignoreCase property indicates whether or not the "i" flag is used with the regular expression. ignoreCase is a read-only property of an individual regular expression instance.

```
var regex1 = new RegExp('foo');
var regex2 = new RegExp('foo', 'i');

console.log(regex1.test('Football'));
// expected output: false

console.log(regex2.ignoreCase);
// expected output: true

console.log(regex2.test('Football'));
// expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

`var regExp = /the word/i`

For more on regex : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp